In the the TLS 1.2 registry key, why are there two sub keys "Server" and "Client"?
The registry key:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2
Has two sub keys Client and Server. What do they signify?
If my application requires TLS 1.2 and only the Client sub key exists under TLS 1.2, is this fine?

That depends if the application is a server (listening for connections) or client (makes a connection to a server).

All of the Windows SCHANNEL TLS/SSL protocols do this, and it's because you may need different behaviors whether your device is receiving the connection or requesting the connection.
For example, let's say you have a fully-headless web server running Server Core — no GUI at all. This is a public web server and you want to lock it down tight... ensuring this server only accepts requests using the latest TLS 1.3. Even on a system like this, the  web application may itself still need to make requests to external APIs. Maybe one of those APIs can only do TLS 1.2, and does not yet support 1.3.
In this situation, if there were only one key, you would be forced to either lower the security limit of your public-facing web service, or setup a completely different server to proxy your API requests — and since we're imaging a world with only one key, this proxy would still need to be exposed to incoming TLS 1.2 requests!
This way you can set your client key to allow TLS 1.2, while still restricting the server keys to have 1.3 as the only option.


"That sounds like I should also be setting this for each application?"

Imagine we could do this: you'd need a place to register each application, and have to update settings every time you changed any apps. Some servers might pretty much never change once configured, and that might be fine, but for a lot of machines that's just too much noise. This is complicated enough already... better to let the application manage this, and build it into the apps to know what version they should use. Even with that setup, you'd still want a place to set a default minimum. And so now we come full circle... these registry keys are the place for that minimum.


"Why not have one setting for the minimum required client and server versions (okay, that's two settings), instead of needing to set this for each protocol?"

That would be nice. There is one advantage to this option, and that is we can enable just a single specific old protocol to support a specific old application, instead of needing to enable that old protocol and everything else newer. So if you have something you need to continue supporting for a while that still needs to make TLS 1.0 connections, you don't also need to enable TLS 1.1. But generally I hope we're not doing that, meaning a single place to set the minimum versions for client and server would be nice.

The really disappointing thing is it's taking Microsoft so long to provide sensible out-of-box defaults. This should have been the default for new installs  (in-place upgrades should preserve what's there) since Server 2016, the first release after Poodle and a full two years later (less just two days), but it's not even in Server 2022. My understanding we're finally getting this for Server 2025. So here we are in 2024, nearly 10 years after the original Poodle disclosure, still needing to manually configure new server installs to handle this.
